# How can I change a dependencies for an installed Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, bundler

I'm using rbenv and have installed the gem Photocopier, which provides a simple way to copy a file from a server to the local environment. This gem has a dependency on the gem net-ssh version 6.1. For reasons unknown to me (version of Ruby? version of macos Ventura?) I need to use a more recent version of net-ssh, for example 7.2.1, which I have installed.

Problem is that I don't know how to change the dependency. I have tried to modify the original gemspec file for Photocopier from

```
spec.add_dependency 'net-ftp', '~> 0.1.3'
spec.add_dependency 'net-scp', '~> 3.0'
spec.add_dependency 'net-sftp', '~> 3.0'
spec.add_dependency 'net-ssh', '~> 6.1'
```

to:

```
spec.add_dependency 'net-ftp'
spec.add_dependency 'net-scp'
spec.add_dependency 'net-sftp'
spec.add_dependency 'net-ssh', '~> 7.2.1'
```

and invoked bundle install, which results in a Gemfile.lock which looks OK:

```
PATH
  remote: .
  specs:
    photocopier (1.4.1)
      activesupport (~> 6.1)
      net-ftp
      net-scp
      net-sftp
      net-ssh (~> 7.2.1)
      net-ssh-gateway (~> 2.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activesupport (6.1.7.7)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    ast (2.4.2)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.3)
    date (3.3.4)
    diff-lcs (1.5.1)
    docile (1.4.0)
    i18n (1.14.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    json (2.7.1)
    language_server-protocol (3.17.0.3)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    minitest (5.22.3)
    net-ftp (0.3.4)
      net-protocol
      time
    net-protocol (0.2.2)
      timeout
    net-scp (4.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5, < 8.0.0)
    net-sftp (4.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 5.0.0, < 8.0.0)
    net-ssh (7.2.1)
    net-ssh-gateway (2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 4.0.0)
    parallel (1.24.0)
    parser (3.3.0.5)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
      racc
    pry (0.14.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    pry-byebug (3.10.1)
      byebug (~> 11.0)
      pry (>= 0.13, < 0.15)
    racc (1.7.3)
    rainbow (3.1.1)
    rake (13.1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.9.0)
    rexml (3.2.6)
    rspec (3.13.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.13.0)
    rspec-core (3.13.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.13.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.13.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.13.0)
    rspec-support (3.13.1)
    rubocop (1.62.1)
      json (~> 2.3)
      language_server-protocol (>= 3.17.0)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 3.3.0.2)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.8, < 3.0)
      rexml (>= 3.2.5, < 4.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.31.1, < 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 2.4.0, < 3.0)
    rubocop-ast (1.31.2)
      parser (>= 3.3.0.4)
    rubocop-capybara (2.20.0)
      rubocop (~> 1.41)
    rubocop-factory_bot (2.25.1)
      rubocop (~> 1.41)
    rubocop-rake (0.6.0)
      rubocop (~> 1.0)
    rubocop-rspec (2.27.1)
      rubocop (~> 1.40)
      rubocop-capybara (~> 2.17)
      rubocop-factory_bot (~> 2.22)
    ruby-progressbar (1.13.0)
    simplecov (0.22.0)
      docile (~> 1.1)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.11)
      simplecov_json_formatter (~> 0.1)
    simplecov-html (0.12.3)
    simplecov_json_formatter (0.1.4)
    time (0.3.0)
      date
    timeout (0.4.1)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    unicode-display_width (2.5.0)
    zeitwerk (2.6.13)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86_64-darwin-22

DEPENDENCIES
  bundler (~> 2.2)
  photocopier!
  pry-byebug (~> 3.9)
  rake (~> 13.0)
  rspec (~> 3.10)
  rubocop (~> 1.6)
  rubocop-rake (~> 0.5)
  rubocop-rspec (~> 2.0)
  simplecov (~> 0.20)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.5.6
```

I use this simple Ruby script to test:

```
require 'photocopier'
ssh = Photocopier::SSH.new(
  host: 'xxx.com',
  user: 'yyy'
)
# downloads a file and returns the content
puts ssh.get('testfile.txt')
```

It crashes and the error log shows that the wrong version of net-ssh is loaded:

```
from /X/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:251:in `new'
from /X/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:251:in `start'
from /X/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/photocopier-1.4.1/lib/photocopier/ssh.rb:71:in `session'
from /X/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/photocopier-1.4.1/lib/photocopier/ssh.rb:18:in `get'
```

The question is where the dependency on the version 6.1.0 of net-ssh comes from and how I can change it to load the version 7.2.1 instead.

Comment: You can fork gem, modify its gemfile and use your fork

Comment: How is this different from changing the gemfile on the local copy I already installed?

Comment: Worked! Thanks. But my question about difference with changing the gemfile on the local copy remains. What I did this time was to use the command "gem build" with the gemspec file as parameter, followed by "gem install". My guess is that it was the "gem build" that did the trick

Comment: Did you `bundle exec` the test script?